# Outlook and Gmail blocking images off an SSL Newsletter

Tags: ssl, outlook

I have a newsletter tool that, well, shows newsletters. Well, the site was on non-SSL hosting and now is on an SSL host. When a user receives the newsletter in Gmail or Outlook the images have a blue question mark on it and the image doesn't show. They can click the 'view in browser' option and everything shows up fine.

This is also with images displayed option turned on in both Outlook and Gmail.

Here's where I think I see the problem - the site does not have it's own SSL cert. It's using a server one so there is a name mismatch.

Would that be the reason why the images are not showing up in Outlook/Gmail? If so, would the solution be to get an SSL cert that matches the domain name?

Answer (score 0):

> Here's where I think I see the problem - the site does not have it's own SSL cert. It's using a server one so there is a name mismatch.

The certificate you're using must be valid for the host name you're using (see RFC 2818, Section 3.1). If this is not the case, your HTTPS server isn't set up properly, so you shouldn't be surprised clients don't like it.

> They can click the 'view in browser' option and everything shows up
>   fine.

Presumably, this works because your users are willing to ignore an error message, which they shouldn't do.

Comment: That is correct. Users click to accept the cert and so get no issues whatsoever. I was just curious on the email part. I guess Outlook and Gmail are trying to pull in the background and when they pull the images they see it doesn't match the cert so the ? comes up.

Comment: Yes, these messages that allow the warnings to be bypassed are usually only presented when they're related to the main URL; disabling warnings this way isn't possible for embedded content. The real issue is that they accept a cert that they probably shouldn't. Don't teach your users to ignore warnings.